# Android - XMLParser SAX - xml not well-formed

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

I have to retrieve datas from a XML got from webservice.

I use SAX parser, like follow:

```
   URL url = new URL(webservice_url);
   SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
   SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
   XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
   NewsHandler handler = new NewsHandler();
   xr.setContentHandler(handler);
   xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<offerte_prodotti>
 <num_pagine>154</num_pagine>
  <product>
    <id>6284</id>
    <nome>Product description</nome>
    <immagine>http://www.ownservercgi.com/images/cgi012548.jpg</immagine>
    <euro>27.00</euro>
    <scadenza>24/06/2014</scadenza>
    <sconto>50%</sconto>
  </product>
</offerte_prodotti>
```

In the application, i use SAX for all XML parser operations and it works fine using the same code.
This time, it gives me an error:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 3292: not well-formed (invalid token)
at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:515)
```

I tought i was a special chars issue, but the other methods in other activities works well using the code i posted.

Is it a XML file problem? Or can i solve it via code?

Answer (score 0):

The XML is not well formed - specifically, the opening "offerte_prodotti" element is not closed.  The XML *should* be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<offerte_prodotti>
 <num_pagine>154</num_pagine>
  <product>
    <id>6284</id>
    <nome>Product description</nome>
    <immagine>http://www.ownservercgi.com/images/cgi012548.jpg</immagine>
    <euro>27.00</euro>
    <scadenza>24/06/2014</scadenza>
    <sconto>50%</sconto>
  </product>
</offerte_prodotti>
```

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i didn't notice that. I edited the question, i didn't copy the entire XML file. What a huge mistake ...